# Can you use Multi Currency in Cart Throb

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, shopping-cart, currency

I need to find an option to allow Multi Currency in Cart Throb checkout.  Is there a way to automatically change the currency based on the customers country code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're after is: https://github.com/CartThrob/addon-multi-location-settings-manager

Found via this forum post: http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/4884/, and this one: http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/4622/P15/#28813

They look a little outdated (last update 2 years ago!) so don't know how relevent it is to the current release.

Hopefully that helps ;)

Comment: I'm using this successfully on a multi-currency site. For the latest EE 2.x version you'll need to use Caroline Blaker's fork linked-to from the bottom of this issue: https://github.com/CartThrob/addon-multi-location-settings-manager/issues/4